# How to count and print the occurence of a column in multiple files using awk

Tags: awk, count

I have multiple tab delim text files in the format shown below:

```
 File1.txt
 Sample    Ind    Start    col1    col2    col3
  ID1       1      1       f       g       f
  ID1       1      2       f       g       f
  ID1       1      3       f       g       f
  ID1       1      5       f       g       f

File2.txt
 Sample    Ind    Start    col1    col2    col3
  ID2       1      1       f       g       f
  ID2       1      2       f       g       f
  ID2       1      4       f       g       f
  ID2       1      5       f       g       f
  ID2       1      6       f       g       f

 File3.txt
 Sample    Ind    Start    col1    col2    col3
  ID3       1      1       f       g       f
  ID3       1      3       f       g       f
  ID3       1      7       f       g       f
```

I would like to count the number of times the columns 2 and 3 i.e. columns '
Ind' and 'Start' found in total number of files and print the count and Sample to a new column.

The output should look like:

```
  Sample    Ind    Start    col1    col2    col3    Count    Samples
  ID1       1      1       f       g       f         3    ID1,ID2,ID3
  ID1       1      2       f       g       f         2    ID1,ID2
  ID1       1      3       f       g       f         2    ID1,ID3
  ID1       1      5       f       g       f         2    ID1,ID2
  ID2       1      6       f       g       f         1    ID2
  ID3       1      7       f       g       f         1    ID3
```

This is a toy example with 3 files, and in real scenario it should work with 'n' files in the directory. Could someone provide an awk solution to do this.

Comment: You didn't show what you've tried, and you've not really described how the values in `col1` .. `col3` in the output should be handled, but otherwise, this is a good question with sample input and desired output.

Comment: The values in col1...col3 may/may not differ between the files. Only the columns 'Ind' and 'Start' will match between the files. And the ouput can be from one of those files with same 'Ind' and 'Start' irrespective of col1..col3. I hope this solution does the same.

Comment: My solution chooses the first line for a given 'Ind' and 'Start' combination. You can experiment with different values in col1..col3 in different files to see that is what happens (or remove the condition before the assignment to pick up the last line that matches, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Superficially, this would do the job:

```
awk 'NR == 1  { OFS="\t"; print $0, "Count", "Samples"; next }
     FNR == 1 { next }
              { if (line[$2,$3] == "")
                    line[$2,$3] = $0;
                count[$2,$3]++;
                if (idlist[$2,$3] != "")
                    idlist[$2,$3] = idlist[$2,$3] "," $1
                else
                    idlist[$2,$3] = $1
              }
     END      { for (idx in count) print line[idx], count[idx], idlist[idx]; }
    ' File*.txt
```

I had to make an assumption since the question doesn't state or illustrate how different values in 'col1', 'col2' and 'col3' should be handled, if at all.  I've assumed that the first line with the given values in 'Ind' and 'Start' are representative enough.  If there's a different rationale required, then a new question should be asked.

Note that the sequence of values in the output is not guaranteed.

Running the script above on the data in the question on Mac OS X 10.10.5 with the BSD `awk` yielded:

```
 Sample    Ind    Start    col1    col2    col3 Count   Samples
  ID1       1      1       f       g       f    3   ID1,ID2,ID3
  ID1       1      2       f       g       f    2   ID1,ID2
  ID1       1      3       f       g       f    2   ID1,ID3
  ID2       1      4       f       g       f    1   ID2
  ID1       1      5       f       g       f    2   ID1,ID2
  ID2       1      6       f       g       f    1   ID2
  ID3       1      7       f       g       f    1   ID3
```

Using GNU `awk` on the same machine and same data set yielded:

```
 Sample    Ind    Start    col1    col2    col3 Count   Samples
  ID1       1      5       f       g       f    2   ID1,ID2
  ID2       1      6       f       g       f    1   ID2
  ID3       1      7       f       g       f    1   ID3
  ID1       1      1       f       g       f    3   ID1,ID2,ID3
  ID1       1      2       f       g       f    2   ID1,ID2
  ID1       1      3       f       g       f    2   ID1,ID3
  ID2       1      4       f       g       f    1   ID2
```